# HttpReponseMessage returns 404 when making call to api in C#

Tags: c#, json, httpclient

I am trying to follow these guidelines to make a call to their API and get a prefilled QR code in return.

https://developer.swish.nu/api/qr-codes/v1#pre-filled-qr-code

But I get error 404 not found back, this is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mpc.getswish.net/qrg-swish");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var json = new {
payee = new {value = "1234", editable = false}, 
amount = new {value = 100, editable = false},
message = new {value = "test message", editable = false},
format = "png"
};
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
"/api/v1/prefilled", json);
```

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't shown how your `client` is defined. My guess is that its `BaseAddress` is wrong. The best tool for problems like this is [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) -- take a look at exactly what request your code is making

Comment: @canton7 Hi, updated my question with the client. Can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong. Okay thank you will look into that!

Comment: I suspect it's probably the leading `/` before `/api`: that might be stripping off the `qrg-swish` part of the URI

Comment: How do you mean? @canton7

Comment: @canton7 I moved the "/" after "qrq-swish" instead. And now I get error 400 bad request instead.

Comment: That means you're now posting to the right address, but your request is wrong somehow. Look at the response message to see if the server told you anything useful about what was wrong?

Comment: @canton7 no nothing other than "bad request" :(

Comment: See my edited answer, where I clearly show that the server *is* giving you a helpful response

Comment: @canton7 thank you so much!! I am very new to this so I didn't know you could read the response content like that. I am so grateful, thank you again!

Comment: @Malin If canton answer helped you out, you can accept it by clicking on the green tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mpc.getswish.net/qrg-swish");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/v1/prefilled", json);
```

The problem is the leading `/` in the path passed to `PostAsJsonAsync`, and the lack of trailing `/` in the `BaseAddress`. Change that to:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mpc.getswish.net/qrg-swish/");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/v1/prefilled", json);
```

---

`HttpClient` combines the path passed to `PostAsJsonAsync` with the value of `HttpClient.BaseAddress` by doing `new Uri(BaseAddress, path)`, [see here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs,771).

If we try this out:

```
var baseUri = new Uri("https://mpc.getswish.net/qrg-swish");
var result = new Uri(baseUri, "/api/v1/prefilled");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

We get the result:

```
https://mpc.getswish.net/api/v1/prefilled
```

Looking at the [Remarks for `new Uri(Uri baseUri, string relativeUri)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-uri-ctor(system-uri-system-string)), we see:

> If the `baseUri` has relative parts (like `/api`), then the relative part must be terminated with a slash, (like `/api/`), if the relative part of `baseUri` is to be preserved in the constructed Uri.
>
> Additionally, if the `relativeUri` begins with a slash, then it will replace any relative part of the `baseUri`

So in order to preserve the path at the end of `BaseAddress`, it needs to end in a `/`, and the path passed to `PostAsJsonAsync` needs to **not** start with a `/`.

---

With that in place, we get a 400 Bad Request rather than a 404 Not Found. Let's take a look at the response body, and see whether the server is telling us anything useful:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
            "api/v1/prefilled", json);
Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

We get:

```
BadRequest
{"timestamp":"2022-03-09T10:14:45.292+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Invalid phone number length","path":"/qrg-swish/api/v1/prefilled"}
```

So, our phone number isn't valid: it's too short. Let's fix that:

```
payee = new {value = "01234567890", editable = false},
```

Now we get:

```
BadRequest
{"timestamp":"2022-03-09T10:15:30.675+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"The size parameter is required when using format PNG","path":"/qrg-swish/api/v1/prefilled"}
```

Right, we need to specify a size. In fairness, the docs do say:

> Size of the QR code. The code is a square, so width and height are the same. **Not required if the format is svg.**

So let's do that:

```
size = 300,
```

And there we have it, success!